# PHP string "contains"

Tags: php, regex, string

What would be the most efficient way to check whether a string contains a "." or not?

I know you can do this in many different ways like with [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) or loop through the string to see if it contains a dot (".").

Comment: [`strpos()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Answer (score 494, accepted):

### PHP 8 or newer:

Use the [`str_contains`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php) function.

```
if (str_contains($str, "."))
{
    echo 'Found it';
}

else
{
    echo 'Not found.';
}
```

### PHP 7 or older:

```
if (strpos($str, '.') !== FALSE)
{
    echo 'Found it';
}

else
{
    echo 'Not found.';
}
```

Note that you need to use the `!==` operator. If you use `!=` or `<>` and the `'.'` is found at position `0`, the comparison will evaluate to true because `0` is loosely equal to `false`.

Comment: +1 for "This will cause you to point a production website at a development database over the weekend, causing no end of joy when you return monday."

Comment: Replace strpos with stripos for case insensitive searches.

Comment: @JordanArseno What makes you say that? Nested code? You suggest he encloses it into a function?

Comment: `if (count(explode('.', $string)) != 2) { //string don't have dot }`

Comment: @TahirYasin This is incorrect - what if there are multiple dots... This will cause you to point a _development_ website at a _production_ database, erasing it and causing no end of joy when you return Monday

Comment: @Penn The question is to find if a given string contains dot, and the code I posted will work perfectly fine for that purpose (either there is one dot or multiple) but if you are using it in some other scenario where you need to take care of other parameters as well then it's a logical fault and you can not blame the code.

Comment: @tahir-yasin It will fail for multiple periods as the count will be more than 2. But why create all of this overhead in the first place when strpos is faster, memory efficient, more readable,  and exists specifically for this purpose.

Answer (score 66):

You can use these string functions,

[strstr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) — Find the first occurrence of a string

[stristr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) — Case-insensitive strstr()

[strrchr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php) — Find the last occurrence of a character in a string

[strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) — Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string

[strpbrk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpbrk.php) — Search a string for any of a set of characters

If that doesn't help then you should use `preg` regular expression

[preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) — Perform a regular expression match

Answer (score 7):

You can use  `stristr()` or `strpos()`. Both *return false* if nothing is found.

Comment: It's very important to note that you cannot check for "falsy", it has to be false. Use the identical operator (=== or !==), as strpos and stristr return 0 as the 0th position, but if you use an "equal to" (== or !=) it believe that it is false.

Comment: @Mattisdada Very good point, thanks for pointing that out.